# Add branch from local PC to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I create branch on my local PC, and I want to push this branch to GitHub.

I'm using IDEA CE and there is two plugins that used: Git Integration, GitHub.

So now when I wanted to look on changes between my local master and NewBranch. And I realized that they are equivalent now (Git integration plugin says that).

What should I do in order not to soil my master branch on GitHub, and add there new branch?

Comment: Did you create a local branch (as in not master) or just checkout what you fetched? I don't use IDEA CE but when I create a local branch then push it upstream it creates the branch on github just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are on master branch and then you created a new branch called `experiment` on you local repository:

```
git checkout -b experiment
```

Now you didn't make any changes (or your IDEA CE doesn't show any difference as you state in your question). But, you want to push `experiment` branch to your remote repository on github. For that you can do:

```
git push -u origin experiment
```

And it should push your `experiment` branch on github.